# Difference between ADO.NET 1.0 and 3.5 using RowFilter and strings?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, dataview, rowfilter

I have recently been tasked with upgrading an application from .net 1.1 to 3.5 and came across a RowFilter on a DataView that had a different behavior between the two versions.

Here is my code block in 1.1 that works in 1.1 but not 3.5. I get the following error trying to run this in 3.5 "Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32"
Both the 1.1 and 3.5 are hitting the same database, I am just confused as to how 1.1 sees the string parameter and treats it as a string without having to put tic marks around it but in 3.5 it sees rptNum and requires you to put tics around it. The field in the dv is a string DataType.

```
    private DataView BuildDataView(string rptNum) {
        DataView dv = null;

        if(dt != null) {
            dv=new DataView(dt);
            dv.RowFilter="reporting_number = " + rptNum;
        }

        return dv;
    }
```

Here is my code block in 3.5 changed so that it works. I had to add tic marks around the string parameter so that it would treat it as a string.

```
    private DataView BuildDataView(string rptNum) {
        DataView dv = null;

        if(dt != null) {
            dv=new DataView(dt);
            dv.RowFilter="reporting_number = '" + rptNum + "'";
        }

        return dv;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the error message:

```
"Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32
```

it sounds as though the value of rptNum causing the error is numerical (although the column of String type): just a guess, but maybe version 1.1 looks first at the value of the variable in the filter and is forgiving enough to process it if the filter clause **can** be interpreted as given by the user, whereas in 3.5 the type cast takes precedence. Do you get the an error message if rptNum is non-numerical when run in version 1.1 of your code?

Comment: OK, that would suggest that type checking does not take place "up front" in 1.1, which seems to be the case in 3.5.